# How to detect minimum Date value in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm very new to Angular technology and I'm facing a small issue in our code.

I need to adds a estimated arrival time to our current display (so obviously it's a Date type). The data is coming from the c# server, we everything else for the purpose of querying for the data is already built. It can be displayed like this below:

[image: UI Disaplay]

If I don't format the date, it will look like this: 0001-01-01T00:00:00

But as you can see, the issue is that when the arrival time reset in the server and then queried by the angular app, the minimum date time will be displayed on the UI. However, I'd like to make it display an empty space instead (or an empty string, whatever would makes sense here.)

Is there any way to detect this minimum date time value, and then instead print out an empty space or string (for example, like '&nbsp')?

The html code is this:

```
<div>
    <label>ETA</label>
    <div>{{ eta | date: 'hh:mm a MM/dd' | default: '&nbsp;' }}</div>
</div>
```

The code from the component type script is, it's coming from an incident object we defined:

```
  get eta(): Date {
    return this.incident?.eta;
  }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "minimum date time value"? Do you know the exact date and time of it?

Comment: @Lynx242 It seems to be 0001-01-01T00:00:00 in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this then:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <label>ETA</label>
    <div *ngIf="!isMinimumDateTimeValue(eta)">{{ eta | date: 'hh:mm a MM/dd'}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="isMinimumDateTimeValue(eta)">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
isMinimumDateTimeValue(eta: Date): Boolean {
    return new Date(eta).getTime() === new Date('1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM').getTime();
}
```

Comment: it's telling me that eta.getTime() is not a function.
  I have exactly the same thing you have I think. isMinimumDateTimeValue(eta: Date): Boolean {
    return eta.getTime() === new Date('1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM').getTime();
  }

Comment: Somehow the eta here is of type "string" while the parameter specified that this should be a DateTime

Comment: Sorry, I had to leave the PC yesterday. I changed the code taking into account that `eta` is a `string`. Should do now. If it helped you, please mark this answer as solution.